# Dividing shapefile into two parts using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, splitting

I have a shapefile, as shown in the below image.

[image]

I want to split it into two different shapefiles, as shown in the second image.

[image]

How can I achieve this using Python?

What I have tried so far is shown below.

```
import geopandas as gpd ; import shapefile ; import numpy as np ; import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ;  

lat_1=6 ; lat_2=20 ; lon_1=70 ; lon_2=90
A=gpd.read_file(shp_file)
points=[]
for shape_rec in A.shapeRecords():
    #print(shape_rec)
     pts = pd.DataFrame(np.array(shape_rec.shape.points))
     pts.columns=['lon','lat']
     points.append(pts) 
points_1=pd.concat(points)

points_2=points_1[(points_1.lon >=lon_1)&(points_1.lon <=lon_2) & (points_1.lat >=lat_1)&(points_1.lat <=lat_2)] 


gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame( points_2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points_2.lon , points_2.lat ), crs='EPSG:4326')
gdf.drop(['lat', 'lon'], axis=1, inplace=True)  # optional
gdf.to_file(main+'shp_files/test.shp')
```

This gives the output as a line of multiple points.

Comment: Make a copy of the data.  Read the geometry of the copy and delete any geometry that have x values above,  below, or both above or below your lines of interest.  Save and repeat.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It seems I have already done what you said. I divided the points into two sets based on lat lon limits and created points, which are then written as a shapefile. But I got a straight-line shapefile instead of the country boundary.

Comment: Identify those coordinates that you want to use as a north / south break line.  Make as many copies of the data that you want polygons for.  Use something like Shapely to iterate the xy values of the polygons.  If the y value is above (or below) one of your break lines than delete that vertex from your copy.  After completion save the record.  Repeat that procedure for the next polygon.  After it is all done you can merge the polygons into a single shapefile.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474549/extract-points-coordinates-from-a-polygon-in-shapely